# What are the existing build targets for MSBuild?

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

MSBuild allows you to specify build-targets such as `Build` or `Clean` with `-target:<build-target>` (Example: `MSBuild.exe -target:Clean`).

Of course, a developer can define their own target using a `.targets` xml file.

However, some targets, such as `Build` or `Clean`, are pre-defined by Microsoft.

What is the list of all default pre-defined build-targets that are common for all .NET languages?

Comment: Good hint! So the default BeforeBuild and AfterBuild targets actually don't do anything unless we override them?

Comment: Correct.  `BeforeBuild` is defined as `<Target Name="BeforeBuild"/>`.  `AfterBuild` is defined as `<Target Name="AfterBuild"/>`.  They are just empty xml elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the command `msbuild -targets` to generate a list of current targets.

Answer (score 40):

The standard build-targets that are common for all .NET languages are defined at [Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets](https://github.com/microsoft/msbuild/blob/master/src/Tasks/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets).

Here is the full list of build targets (as of Nov 12, 2020):

- Build
- Rebuild
- Clean
- Run
- Publish
- PublishOnly
- ResolveReferences
- ResolveProjectReferences
- ResolveAssemblyReferences
- GenerateBindingRedirects
- PrepareResources
- ResGen
- Compile
- GenerateManifests
- PrepareForRun
- CopyFilesToOutputDirectory
- CoreBuild
- BuildGenerateSources
- BuildCompile
- BuildLink
- CopyRunEnvironmentFiles
- BuildOnlySettings
- PrepareForBuild
- GetFrameworkPaths
- GetReferenceAssemblyPaths
- AssignLinkMetadata
- PreBuildEvent
- UnmanagedUnregistration
- GetTargetFrameworkVersion
- AssignProjectConfiguration
- GetTargetPath
- GetTargetPathWithTargetPlatformMoniker
- GetNativeManifest
- ResolveNativeReferences
- GenerateBindingRedirects
- GenerateBindingRedirectsUpdateAppConfig
- ResolveSDKReferences
- FindInvalidProjectReferences
- ExpandSDKReferences
- ExportWindowsMDFile
- DesignTimeResolveAssemblyReferences
- ResolveComReferences
- PrepareResourceNames
- AssignTargetPaths
- GetItemTargetPaths
- SplitResourcesByCulture
- CreateCustomManifestResourceNames
- ResolveKeySource
- GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute
- GenerateAdditionalSources
- GenerateSerializationAssemblies
- CreateSatelliteAssemblies
- GenerateSatelliteAssemblies
- ComputeIntermediateSatelliteAssemblies
- SetWin32ManifestProperties
- GenerateApplicationManifest
- GenerateDeploymentManifest
- GetCopyToOutputDirectoryItems
- UnmanagedRegistration
- IncrementalClean
- CleanReferencedProjects
- CleanPublishFolder
- PostBuildEvent
- SetGenerateManifests
- PublishBuild
- AllProjectOutputGroups
- BuiltProjectOutputGroup
- DebugSymbolsProjectOutputGroup
- DocumentationProjectOutputGroup
- SatelliteDllsProjectOutputGroup
- SourceFilesProjectOutputGroup
- ContentFilesProjectOutputGroup
- SGenFilesOutputGroup
- GetResolvedSDKReferences
- PriFilesOutputGroup
- SDKRedistOutputGroup
- GetInstalledSDKs
- Restore
- BeforeBuild
- AfterBuild
- BeforeRebuild
- AfterRebuild
- BeforeResolveReferences
- AfterResolveReferences
- BeforeResGen
- AfterResGen
- BeforeCompile
- AfterCompile
- BeforeClean
- AfterClean
- BeforePublish
- AfterPublish

The targets that are prefixed with `Before` or `After` are intended to be overridden in projects.

Comment: Hi cowlinator, thanks for your sharing and please mark your reply as answer and that will help other community members who easier search this useful information, it just a reminder :)

Comment: Msbuild also has the target `restore` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-restore#restore-using-msbuild